# Android - Setting TextView as Wrap_Content Programmatically Doesn't Work

Tags: android, layout, parameters, textview, android-relativelayout

I used the following code to make a `TextView` programmatically:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
someRelativeLayout.addView(someTextView, params);
```

When I look at the TextView after its creation, however, it looks cut off. I've tried decreasing the font size, but it's still cut off. Size doesn't seem to be a factor.

I tried setting the width to `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`, which does allow the entire word to be displayed, but it seemed to have nullified the effects of `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` because it then got aligned to the left of the `RelativeLayout`.

How do I make it so that it would be truly content-wrapped and horizontally-centered within the layout?

Comment: Try setting the gravity of your textView and just use your current solution.

Comment: My bad, I've somehow misread HORIZONTAL into VERTICAL. You could still use the `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` for the `TextView` and set the content gravity(`setGravity()`) to `CENTER` for the `TextView`.

Comment: Excellent. That works. If you make your comment an answer. I'll accept it.